# Service Stack set HttpCookie.Secure Flag / Attribute?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to set the Secure Flag on Session Cookies (ie https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag).

I've attempted:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
...
Config.OnlySendSessionCookiesSecurely = true;
...

}
```

Without success - when viewing in Fiddler, Chrome Developer Tools, etc - the Secure Flag is not being set.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `SetConfig()` when configuring ServiceStack, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    OnlySendSessionCookiesSecurely = true,
});
```

Comment: I added that to my SetConfig and verified that my  base.Config.OnlySendSessionCookiesSecurely is set to true, but when I inspect the cookies in my Application_EndRequest(...) handler (ie Request.Cookies["ss-id"].Secure) - they're still set to false.  Any further ideas?

Comment: @mjj It also needs to be https, what does `Request.IsSecureConnection` return?

Comment: That was it.  I was running locally via http.  Thank you for your help and great job with the framework - we're huge fans.